# Would I use a capitalization for vampire?

Tags: fantasy, grammar, capitalization

I have been writing a fantasy story, but I am not sure if I should use capitalization on "vampire" or not. In the first example it's talking about a single vampire, but not specific one. Example:

> "Who in their right mind would kill a vampire, but not the person the vampire had bitten?"

At other moments, it is talking about all vampires, and in that case, would it be capitalized? Example:

> "And Vampires should need us to show them how to be ‘good’ or ‘normal’, they should learn it themselves."

And finally, would I capitalize vampire when referring to the king of vampires?

> "No way in hell am I saying that the Vampire King helped me.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vampire is not a unique concept and thus does not need capitalization.  If "vampires" are of the unique Kizzard Clan then they would.  Proper titles like Vampire King should be capitalized as they refer to a specific individual or group of individuals who held that Specific Title (The President or The Presidents of the United States but not "a president of a country").